# Binding to the ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, telerik, viewmodel

I have my own defined GroupHeaderTemplate in the RadGridView.
Here is the picture
[image]

A part of the code goes here:

```
TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                 Text="{Binding Group.Items[0].Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 Foreground="#50A0DA" 
                 FontWeight="Bold"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Width="Auto"/>
```

For example if I edit **Test Levon** to **Edited Text** I cannot get the edition in my ViewModel. How can I achieve it? Is there a way to bind the edited text to a property in my ViewModel?

P.S. This is a Silverlight application.

Comment: Have u used inotifypropertychanged for Group class?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The Problem is solved already in a different way, but anyway the Group is a property from GroupViewModel, so this is telerik implementation, and I can't do anything with it.